# Rails invalid date error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using [this](https://github.com/watu/table_builder) gem to setup a calendar in my app. Everything is working fine except the arrows that change the month.. Getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#show

invalid date
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"month"=>"2012-06",
 "id"=>"7"}
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @friends = @user.friends.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
   end
```

Console:

```
Started GET "/users/7?month=2012-06" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-29 21:30:04 -0700
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"month"=>"2012-06", "id"=>"7"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 7 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms

ArgumentError (invalid date):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Date.parse("2012-06")` causing the error.

If the date is not significant, you may try this: `Date.parse("#{params[:month]}-01")`

Answer (score 2):

```
It is cause due to improper format of the date, the date format is either "%Y-%m-%d" or"%d-%m-%Y" since you have just pass the parameter i.e.
    {"month"=>"2012-06", "id"=>"7"}
you should send the parameter 
    {"month"=>"2012-06-27", "id"=>"7"}
you should send the date also
I had the same problem and solve by adding day in the date parameter.
```

Hope this will help you.